# Why are SUID/GGUID files usually unreadable?

Tags: linux, solaris

I have noticed that on linux that SUID binaries, like login su etc do not have read permission set. What is the reason for this? There must be some history behind? Or is it because you can attach a debugger if you can read the files, and therby run whatever code you wish?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux: setuid programs without read permission](https://superuser.com/questions/67118/linux-setuid-programs-without-read-permission)

Answer (score 1):

This is not my experience, so it may be worth mentioning which distribution you use.

You can't attach a debugger to a suid binary unless you are root.

Reading the binary enables you to look for weaknesses in the program to exploit. But you could download the distribution yourself and install it on your computer where you have root access and examine the programs as you wish. If it's part of the core programs, you can even get the source and examine at the source level.

So there is no point hiding the contents of the files.